# миграция и обновление данных с mysql в postgres

Tags: mysql, python, postgresql

задача: перенос и обновление данных с mysql в postgres, посоветуйте лучшие практики для реализации.
варианты:

1. дропать таблицы и делать постоянно insert данных
2. реализовывать логику для проверки обновились ли некоторые записи, делать их апдейт, а новых insert, возможно есть подводные камни.

что можете посоветовать ?

Comment: ну вообще зависит от того откуда в mysql берутся данные и нужны ли они там. И может тогда было бы проще сделать сразу вставку в postgress, вместо mysql

Comment: нужно все таблицы переносить в postgres и с переодичностью обновлять данные

Comment: Предполагается изменение структуры таблиц в будущем?

Comment: возможно добавление новых полей

Comment: Насколько велик объем данных? Можно спрогнозировать на данном этапе?

Comment: пока сложно сказать, пока данных немного, drop и insert будет эффективен и проще

Comment: @MPyt Есть еще 3й путь - бесплатный продукт oracle golden gate. В него надо пару дней серьезно вкуривать ... Он умеет реплицировать любые данные между любыми СУБД на лету. А drop/insert - довольно опасное мероприятие. Вы можете начать перенос данных, пока вы читаете другой процесс вставит данные, вы их не увидите и дропните таблицу. Так что надежнее все таки select for update и удалять именно перенесенные строки